# Search exact word in unix awk command

Tags: unix, awk

```
awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1 ; c=0}/"month"/{c++} END{print c}'
```

I have stdin :

```
"There are many monthly. 
I love month with Month. 
Don't know what I'm doing. 
I hope I can do month problem. 
Month is my problem."
```

Here in output "monthly" Is also counted in place of month. But I want only "month" To be considered. What should be the correction?

Comment: Which awk version/variety? Maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/349104/awk-match-whole-word

Comment: @NikkiKounder, please do add your sample of expected output in your question to make it more clear.